# Pasar una variable contador de un método a otro

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de Java y tengo la siguiente duda.
Necesito pasar la variable contador, la cual cuenta los números que si terminan con el ultimo dígito que se ingresa por teclado.
Pegaré el código para que me entiendan mejor:

```
package ejercicio_catedra1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Francisco Morales
 */
public class Ejercicio_Catedra1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String captura = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el largo del arreglo");
        int tam = Integer.parseInt(captura);
        int numeros[] = new int[tam];

        int dig_final;
        do {
            String captura2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indíque un dígito de 0 a 9 ");
            dig_final = Integer.parseInt(captura2);
        } while (!(dig_final >= 0 && dig_final <= 9));

        llenarArreglo(numeros, 1, 300);

        int numCorrectos[] = validarNroFinal(numeros, dig_final);

        mostrarCorrectos(numCorrectos, dig_final);
    }

    public static void llenarArreglo(int numeros[], int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("<>---|| ARREGLO INICIAL ||---<>");
        int pos;
        for (int x = 0; x < numeros.length; x++) {
            numeros[x] = ((int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (a - b) + b));
            pos = x + 1;
            System.out.println("Arreglo -- posición " + pos + "--> " + numeros[x]);
        }
    }

    public static int[] validarNroFinal(int numeros[], int num_final) {
        int numCorrectos[] = new int[numeros.length];
        int ultimoNum = 0, contador = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numCorrectos.length; i++) {
            ultimoNum = numeros[i] - (numeros[i] / 10 * 10);

            if (ultimoNum == num_final) {
                numCorrectos[i] = numeros[i];
                contador = contador + 1;
            }
        }
        return numCorrectos;
    }

    public static void mostrarCorrectos(int numCorrectos[], int dig_final) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("NUMEROS CORRECTOS, SEGUN SU SELECCION == " + dig_final);

//        System.out.println("Se encontraron " + contador + " coincidencias");
        for (int j = 0; j < numCorrectos.length; j++) {
            if (numCorrectos[j] != 0) {
                System.out.println(" El número " + numCorrectos[j] + " acaba en " + dig_final);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

en el método **validarNroFinal**, capturé en la variable contador, cada vez que se encuentra una coincidencia, ahora lo que necesito es, pasarla al método **mostrarCorrectos**, para mostrar el número de coincidencias que se encontraron y en caso de que sea cero, indicar que no se encontraron.

Espero me puedan ayudar
Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Declara el **contador como variable de clase** y no local del método a fin de que puedas modificarla desde culaquier lugar de la clase.